# ORACLE number of current week

Tags: oracle

im trying to get the number of current week by this select 
   to_char(sysdate) is 04.JUN.2014

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'WW') from dual;
```

it returns 23, thats okay

but when i do with sysdate-1

```
select to_char(sysdate-1, 'WW') from dual;
```

it returns 22, despite yesterday was also 23-rd week. and  to_char(sysdate-1) is 03.JUN.2014 
i am querying against oracle 11g2

Please, help me understand why this works so?

Comment: I think you want the ISO week: `to_char(sysdate-1, 'IW')`

Comment: yes :) Thank you, i read about specification of WW and IW after your comment:))

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What's a ISO week ?

Comment: @AsfakulIslam: the week number scheme defined by the ISO standard (as opposed to e.g. country specific week numberings) See here for details:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week_number#Week_numbering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WW: Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year.
Jan 1,2014 starts on Wednesday and that's why weeks are starting from Wednesday to Tuesday for this year.

If you use "IW" then weeks will be counting from Monday to Sunday.